# \itshape is to \textit as ?? is to \mathit?

Tags: fonts, listings

In the following example, I've set `listing`'s basic style to `\itshape`. However, the `+` operator is italicized, and so are the parentheses:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{basicstyle=\slshape}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
abc + (def)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: Italicized listing]

How can I use the `\mathit` font instead, and get straight parentheses and operators, but math-style text? Using `\mathit` complains about not being in math mode, of course.

Comment: If you want to type math in a listing, excape to math, see `mathescape` in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I want to do :)

Comment: You could also try `\begin{lstlisting}[identifierstyle=\slshape,basicstyle=\rmfamily]`. But imho this isn't want you want either.

Answer (score 2):

A crude workaround is the redefinition of the symbols using the `literate` feature. It comes with some limitations:

- Every upright symbol needs to be replaced.
- Symbols inside keywords, ... are not recognized.
- Italic correction is not applied between slanted and upright text.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\slshape,
  literate=
    +{{\textup{+}}}1
    ({{\textup{(}}}1
    ){{\textup{)}}}1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
abc + (def)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]